# Find the coordinate of a source image's point opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on a project of image alignment. So far I've computed the warped image using cv2.warpPerspective(). Now to esure the robustness of algorithm I want to do the following:

1. Pick 4 or 5 pixel coordinates from sorce image and find their corresponding pixel points in warped image.
2. Compute the difference b/w these values to that of location of these points in the reference image.

Comment: Invert the matrix and project your points.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [include some code in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @fmw42 thanks for reply. I already tried invertingthe matrix but Its not giving correct locations, not any way near